# Scheme Match all given values in a list before returning true

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I have a problem in my function where I'm only able to match 1 element in a list, as soon as it hits the first match it results #t. but I want to be able to match all the values in the list.

say x1(1111 . 9999), they both should match the list x2(1111 . 124123 . 3781283 . 1298394 . 9999) only then return #t

return #f if x2(1111 . 124123 . 3781283 . 1298394) is like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's with the wacky formatting? It's nor lisp, scheme or racket..

Comment: Sorry, It was just a representation of a list without any language related but the question is related to scheme,lisp,racket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I'm understanding your problem correctly. If so, check out `andmap`

```
(define (match-all xs ys)
  (not (not (andmap (λ (x) (member x ys))
                    xs))))

(match-all '(1 4 5) '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6)) ;; #t, each (1 4 5) is found in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
(match-all '(1 5 9) '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6)) ;; #f, 9 is not found in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

---

If you want to write this without built ins, we can write an all-in-one procedure

```
(define (match-all xs ys)
  (define (member? x ys)
    (cond ((empty? ys) #f)
          ((eq? x (car ys)) #t)
          (else (member? x (cdr ys)))))
  (define (loop xs ys)
    (cond ((empty? xs) #t)
          ((member? (car xs) ys) #t)
          (else (loop (cdr xs) ys))))
  (loop xs ys))
```

---

Otherwise it's best to implement generic procedures and build new procedures using the generics. This helps reduce complexity and keeps cognitive load low

```
(define (andmap f xs)
  (if (empty? xs)
      #t
      (let (x (f (car xs)))
        (if (eq? #f x)
            #f
            (and x (andmap f (cdr xs)))))))

(define (member? x ys)
  (cond ((empty? ys) #f)
        ((eq? x (car ys)) #t)
        (else (member? x (cdr ys)))))

(define (match-all xs ys)
  (andmap (lambda (x) (member? x ys)) xs))
```

Comment: I'm new to scheme, can it be done without andmap, A function where it recurs though the input list and matches all the values in the big list only then return #t, I have a working function where as soon as one element is true it returns but I want it to check all in the input...Thanks

Comment: @user2714430 I made an update that doesn't use andmap

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example:

```
(define (example xs)
  (match xs
    [(list 1111 middle ... 9999)  middle]
    [_                            #f]))
```

And in use:

```
> (example '(1111 2 3 4 9999))
'(2 3 4)
> (example '(1111 2 3 4 5))
#f
```

Note that the middle part is return if the list matches.
If the list doesn't match, false is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to return true only if all the elements of list1 are to be found in list2. If that is correct then your match-all just requires a cond statement (or equivalent structure) with three options:

```
 match-all applied to list1 and list2 is
   if list1 is empty return true
   elseif the car of list1 is not a member of list2 return false
   otherwise return match-all applied to the cdr of list1 and all of list2
```